# HTML5 video currentTime and buffering

Tags: javascript, html5-video, buffering

I have a buffering issue.
On my page (which I access remotely), I have a video that I position using the `currentTime` attribute.

However, it seems like, despite the fact that I do not autobuffer, the video is still buffered until this position.

Is that correct?
Is there a way I can seek to this position without reading the video until this point in time?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are referencing the video asset by http, you probably need to enable pseudo-streaming on your webserver, otherwise the entire video will be transferred even though the browsers might be sending the `&start=` parameters on the request.

Take a look here: http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v4/12207/video-delivery-http-pseudo-streaming

and another comment here: http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/blog/11887/html5-video-not-quite-there-yet